# Visual Studio is doing a rebuild of the unmodified projects when tests are being run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, xunit

We have a solution with ~80 projects. When we run, debug, or write tests, Visual Studio rebuilds projects unnecessarily even though I built the solution before and nothing in the code of the projects was changed in the meantime.

Following this

https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/696

[Visual Studio Rebuilds unmodified projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916729/visual-studio-rebuilds-unmodified-projects)

, the settings that should improve the workflow are:

1. setting the CopyToOutputDirectory to PreserveNewest;
2. turning on Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > Only build startup projects and dependencies on run

, and we have them set them already.

Is there an option to only run tests and not build projects again? Because Visual Studio doesn’t keep track if the projects are up-to-date or not, it just rebuilds them again.

On top of that, we receive this error in the output every time a test is being run
Failed to load extensions from file ‘C:\Users\monit\nuget\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.5.0\build\net6.0\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll’

I’ve tried to troubleshoot this error using the following workarounds:

1. to exclude xUnit’s core assemblies named xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll

[xUnit tests fails when executed by Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869411/xunit-tests-fails-when-executed-by-azure-devops)

2. checked the compatibility between xUnit and xUnit Test Adapter;

3.clean and rebuild the solution;

4. checked project references;
5. delete Nuget cache.

But it didn’t fix the problem and the error is still there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on same machine you built application or a remote machine?  Did you publish?  If remote machine check the bin folder of the build machine for dll files.  Are the dll files also on the deploy machine in the same folder as the c# executable?

Comment: I am running on the same machine that I built my application. I checked, and xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll exist on my machine in the specified location. Wondering what else can I try.

Comment: It should be a reference.  Usually error like this are due to library being loaded a an object instead of a reference or the version isn't correct. I would edit the csproj file and delete all reference to dll.   Then add again.  Usually errors like this are due to the version number being wrong in the csproj file.